# Is killing a bee haram?

Tags: halal-haram, animals

A huge bee came to my bathroom while I was brushing my teeth and was buzzing around, and in panic/due to my fear of such insects I killed it. Would this be considered haram in this scenario? I feel extremely guilty.

Answer (score 1):

> إِنَّا للهِ وَإِنَّـا إِلَيْهِ رَاجِعونَ
>
> Surely we belong to Allah and to Him shall we return
>   - (Quran, 2:156)

The Bee is a important creation of Allah (سبحانه و تعالى) and even has it's own chapter in the Quran, Surat 16 An-Naĥl (The Bee), in which Allah (سبحانه و تعالى) mentions that honey has healing properties - (Quran, 16:69).

We know today that the Bee pollinates various plant life, and without it's work, an estimated 30% of North American consumed food would not have grown.

- (https://beespotter.org/topics/economics/)

Everything belongs to Allah (سبحانه و تعالى) so we should not kill things that He has given life without a shariah valid reason.

> Guilt is a gift from Allah warning you that what you are doing is violating your soul
> -Nouman Ali Khan

But do not lose hope...

> “Say: ‘O My slaves who have transgressed against themselves (by committing evil deeds and sins)! Despair not of the Mercy of Allah, verily Allah forgives all sins. Truly, He is Oft-Forgiving, Most Merciful.”
> - (Quran, 39: 53)